# Conflict between Google Polymer and Highcharts library

Tags: jquery, highcharts, polymer, web-component

I'm developing the a dashboard with combination of Google Polymer and Highcharts library. (Both amazing library..)

When I use both of libraries at the same time, it crashes. Chrome support all the required features in Polymer as natively. So no problem!. In FF and IE, they do not support a feature such as 'HTML Import' where Polymer needs it. So in order to work around, Polymer Developer made a javascript called [webcomponents.js](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/platform.html) where it allows to import html files regardless of browser support. (Obviously webcomponents.js has not been used in Chrome for me)

I have noticed that webcomponents.js mass around with document query selector. (which cause some several issue with Jquery is well.. arhgg)

So I assume that the highcharts library that depends on JQuery may conflict and end up having the issue that I'm having now.. Here are the examples:

[image: Donut chart]

[image: Line chart]

Both examples are captured from IE11.

The order of loading libraries are as follow:

1. webcomponents.js
2. jquery-1.9.1.min.js
3. highcharts.js

Did anyone having a similar issue..? I may need to look into webcomponents.js source code to figure it out but I would like to hear some opinions from experts.

UPDATE1:
I have made a simple test environment in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epavak4y/1/).

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

I have loaded libraries corresponding order and used the same demo codes from Highcharts demo. Seems like working fine on FF or IE. Assuming that the issue could be other libraries that I use or my own code. I will keep update if I find anything else.

UPDATE2:
I noticed that I have used `<link rel="import" ..` but in my code, I downloaded the source code and load as normal javascript way. So I have modified [js-example](http://jsfiddle.net/epavak4y/2/) and as a result, in IE, the example is shown as broken. And it is exactly the same problem that I am having now.

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo, because I run it with polimer, without this issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Um..it might take a time to make it into live demo. Have you tried them in Firefox or IE?

Comment: Yes, so Im justi waiting for the demo.

Comment: The demo is ready under UPDATE2. Click 'js-example' to view.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3775) so let's check it.